# Saving to a variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, var

I have a variable that can be added to with a button click, what I want to do is if one user clicks and adds 1 to the variable, it saves to the code and is viewable for everyone. My code so far is

```html
<div class="game-object">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var clicks = 0;
        function updateClickCount() {
            document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" class "myButton" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push">Press me !!!</button> <br>
    <p4> Number of presses: </p4>
    <div id="clickCount"></div>
</div>
```

I'm new to javascript so can someone please help :)

Comment: If you want to do what I think you want to do then you need to involve a server to persist the value.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the platform !

You need a database to persist the updated value of clicks variable. 
Without it, it is not possible to show the new value to every user.

Without database it is possible that each user can see the value, updated only by him/her (not by other users).

Please, let me know which option is right for you and if you have a server and if you have one, what is the technology stack that you are using there on your server, so I can help you further.